# How center text in "in reverse order"

Tags: html, css

I'm using `text-align: center`. Unfortunately, this property work like this: the remainder remains at the end:

[image]

I need this effect: the remainder remains at the start:

[image]

How to get this effect?

Comment: There is no such CSS rule. Try adding `<br/>` where you want to break your first line

Comment: :( I need universal solution, no to specific case

Comment: Try calculate where to put your `<br/>` via JS. Way too much work. Simply re-design

Answer (score -1):

**Hello, fastq123:**

Please have a look at this code I put together based on your request. Please note that you will need either vanilla or jQuery to achieve this task, I decided to go with jquery to make it faster but both ways will work.I certainly hope this helps, mate. Happy coding!

```js
// Assign the DOM P element to a variable
p = document.getElementById("paragraph");
// Assing p text to another variable
let strParagraph = p.innerHTML;
// Convert it to an array
let strArray = strParagraph.split(" ");
// Reverse elements in the array
let last_element = strArray[strArray.length - 1];
```

```css
.reverse {
text-align:center;
width:420px;
}

.reverse { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 93px; 
  top: 21px; 
  width: 65%; 
  height:60%; 
  display: table; 
}

.reverse p {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: justify; 
}

.reverse p::first-line {
text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="reverse">
          <p id="paragraph">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
</p></div>
```

Comment: It does not make sense: 1. Your text lines then are in reverse order 2. You must manually put line brakes instead of having browser split lines

Comment: Apologies for not making sense, however, would you mind sharing your knowledge and enlighten us with the most assertive solution for this matter? Please, we will be glad to learn from you, folk.